# Qt/C++: Having an MDI child call a function of its parent?

Tags: c++, qt, mdi

I have a Qt Designer Class called MainWindow which is a QMainWindow. This class creates an MDI Area and has children windows, as MDI should.

One of these MDI children, we'll call wndChild which is also a QMainWindow,  needs to spawn a "sibling" (that is, an MDI child of its parent, not an MDI child of its own). I figured the best way to do that would be to create a public function in the parent (MainWindow) which then creates the new MDI child.

The problem is, I'm not sure how to call this function from the child. I tried something like:

```
MainWindow *mdiparent=this->parentWidget();
mdiparent->spawnOtherChild();
```

But QMainWindow::parentWidget returns a pointer to a QWidget, not a QMainWindow, so I of course get an error.

How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [qobject_cast](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qobject.html#qobject_cast) to get a pointer to MainWindow :

```
MainWindow *mdiparent = qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(this->parentWidget());
mdiparent->spawnOtherChild();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately it was pointed out to me that the mdiArea is the parent of this window, and rather than doing something like MainWindow *mdiparent = qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(this->parentWidget()->parentWidget()); I'm just going to store a pointer to the mainwindow. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could define a signal to be emitted by the MDI child. Connect that to a slot in your MainWindow and spawn the other child window from the slot handler.